# Using Set-Clipboard to copy multiple files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy, clipboard

I am trying to copy multiple file paths using "Set-Clipboard" command in PowerShell

Here is the code to copy multiple files that does not work

```
#Individual paths
$a = "C:\Users\me\test\test1.pdf"
$b = "C:\Users\me\test\test2.pdf"

$paths = '"' + $a + '"' + ', ' + '"' + $b + '"'

#Checking path
Write-Host $paths

#Copying to Clipboard
Set-Clipboard -Path $paths
```

But the following code works. The following code copies both "test1.pdf" and "test2.pdf" from their respective locations to clipboard

```
Set-Clipboard -Path "C:\Users\me\test\test1.pdf", "C:\Users\me\test\test2.pdf"
```

But when this string is generated by code, it does not work.

The following also works

```
Set-Clipboard -Path $a, $b
```

In my case, there are a lot of files to copy from different locations. So, I have to generate a string with paths separated by a comma.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Or please suggest an alternate way to copy multiple file paths to clipboard.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$paths = '"' + $a + '"' + ', ' + '"' + $b + '"'` constructs a *single string*, not an *array*, the latter being what [`Set-Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-5.1)'s `-Path` parameter<sup>[1]</sup> expects.

Use `$paths = $a, $b` instead, via `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-).

Explicit double-quoting of values stored in variables is never necessary in PowerShell, not even for values that contain spaces.

---

<sup>[1] Note that the cross-platform *PowerShell (Core) v6+* edition no longer supports this parameter; it only supports copying *text* (strings), presumably due to only providing the least-common-denominator functionality across all platforms. See [GitHub issue #14758](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14758) for a discussion.</sup>